Dynamic React Component Import type issue
Let's say I have a component called PersonalDetailsForm which I import dynamically in my multi wizard registration component RegistrationFormSteps.
When PersonalDetailsForm is loading I want to be able to call its nested component PersonalDetailsForm.Loading to showcase the loading state.
PersonalDetailsForm.Loading.
const PersonalDetailsForm = () => <h1>Test</h1>
const PersonalDetailsFormLoader = () => {
  return <>loading...</>;
};

PersonalDetailsForm.Loading = PersonalDetailsFormLoader;
export default PersonalDetailsForm

Then I import this in my RegistrationFormSteps Component
const PersonalDetailsForm = dynamic(() => import("./personal-details-form"), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <PersonalDetailsForm.Loading />,
});

const loaders = [<TypeSelectionForm.Loading />, <PersonalDetailsForm.Loading />];

In both cases I get this error
 
Property 'Loading' does not exist on type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
Property 'Loading' does not exist on type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>'. 

UPDATE
This problem comes up only when I import components dynamically. If I use regular imports, it works to reference the <Loading/> nested component.

Based on your code, it seems you intend to render a component depending on the current status. Below is the necessary implementation to achieve this behavior according to the provided status.
 import React from "react";    
const PersonalDetailsForm = ({ status }) => {
      const PersonalDetailsFormLoader = () => <div>Loading...</div>;
      const PersonalDetailsFormError = () => <div>Error occurred!</div>;
      const PersonalDetailsFormSucess = () => <div>Success!</div>;
    
      const components = {
        loading: <PersonalDetailsFormLoader />,
        error: <PersonalDetailsFormError />,
        success: <PersonalDetailsFormSucess />,
      };
    
      return <div>{components[status]}</div>;
    };
    
    export default PersonalDetailsForm;

you can import below component in your RegistrationFormSteps
<PersonalDetailsForm status={"loading"} />


Appreciate the answer, however, this is not what I wanted. I could have done it this simple way, however, I manage loading components differently
